# Css not working when upload to the server

Tags: css, spring, jsp, web

I know this question has been asked before but this is a little different case. The thing is, I have same css file for all the screens(jsp files) and in localhost is working perfectly well, but when upload the project to the server the css is not being applied to all of the screens.

I made sure that the link to the css file is correct and the same in all the jsp files.

I took a look at the files uploaded to the server and they are the correct ones (both css and jsp).

I don't understand and can't find a clue in that, so I'd be really thankful if someone can put a little light on this.

Photo of page where css is being working fine:

[image]

Photo of the page where css is not working:

[image]

All of the jsp files are in the same folder and all of the css files too:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `not being applied to all of the screens` sounds to me like a caching issue. Try clearing your browser cache, and forcing a reload of the page. Ctrl + Shift + F5

Comment: Are both jsp files in diferent folders by any chance? Paste both URLs please.

Comment: I have added a photo of the folders with the files, all the jsp files are in the same folder and all the css files are in the same folder...

Comment: I have tried to delete cache but it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a path problem, that's why it works on your localhost, but not on the web hosting service. Make sure to check the path of the folders where your css files are in. When you load them into the web hosting service, the paths might not be the same, as when you were using it on local host. Make sure the path is correct, or re-set to make sure they are pointing to the right places while they being used on the web hosting service.

Comment: As someone that deleted his answer said, for the pictures there was a path problem and had to add a "/" at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, stupid me I was checking the css was correct in the css file for one resolution. But I forgot to copy paste the css to the other resolutions!

As for the images... I had to add a "/" to the begining of the path because don't know why in one jsp worked fine and in the other didn't as you can see in the following photo:

[image]